# How do you perform a secondary sort while maintaining a primary sort

Tags: c++, sorting, selection

For example I am writing a hash table with entries (string key, int count). First I am doing a selection sort to sort each entry by count. Then I want to sort them alphabetically while maintaining the sorted count. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the primary sort.

```
void MyTrends::sortByCount(Entry* arr, int sizeOfArray) {
  int maxIndex; // the index of the element that has the highest count
  for(int i=0; i < sizeOfArray-1; i++){
      maxIndex = i;
      for(int j=i+1; j < m; j++){
          if(arr[j].getCount() > arr[maxIndex].getCount()){ //if the count of element j is higher than the count of the Entry at the current max index then change the max index to j
              maxIndex = j;
          }
      }
      if (maxIndex != i) {
          Entry temp = arr[i]; //next 2 lines + this line are swapping max to first position and old first position to the position the max was in
          arr[i] = arr[maxIndex];
          arr[maxIndex] = temp;
      }
  }
}
```

EDIT: After thinking some more, could this be accomplished by first sorting alphabetically and then using a stable sort to sort by count?

Comment: you are right, if you first sort for the secondary key and use the primary sort key afterwards in a stable sorting algorithm, it should give you the desired result :)

Comment: Do you mean that when we have two elements with the same alphabetical order, the one with the least count should be smaller ?

Comment: Reverse of what you just said.

If you have two keys with the same count, I want the one that is first alphabetically to be displayed first.

Comment: @Slizzered He is right but that still isn't the way to do it. It can all be done in a single sort.

Comment: Ah the best answer down below is a way better way to do it. Thanks to all!

Comment: The obvious way is to only do a single sort, but as the compare operation: if the primary key is equal then return the result of checking the secondary key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is a custom `Entry` comparison operator. E.g.

```
struct Entry {
    int num;
    char letter;
}

bool operator< (const Entry& lhs, const Entry& rhs)
{
    if ( lhs.num == rhs.num )
        return lhs.letter < rhs.letter;
    else
        return lhs.num < rhs.num;
}
```

And then just sort it using custom comparison. The list will be sorted at first by numbers (the `num` member) and then alphabetically using the `letter` member.

Comment: Thank you. That is way more efficient than sorting twice!

Comment: take a look also at implementing lexicographical sort with std::tuple

Answer (score 5):

```
struct Entry {
  int num;
  char letter;
  friend auto make_tie(Entry const&e){
    return std::tie(e.num,e.letter);
  }
  friend bool operator<(Entry const&lhs, Entry const& rhs){
    return make_tie(lhs)<make_tie(rhs);
  }
};
```

this exploits `tuple`'s lexographic sort to order your entry.  `tie` makes a tuple of references.

It requires writing `make_tie`, but once you have that, you get `==` `<` for free, and you can use it for a few other functions too -- serialization, printing, `swap`, etc.

`make_tie` is C++14 -- for C++11 you need to add a `->decltype(std::tie(e.num,e.letter))` between the `)` and `{` of `make_tie`.

Comment: that's exactly what I'd do, upvote! not sure why you want an additional make_tie though, why not directly use `return std::tie(...) < std::tie(...)`?

Comment: @vsoftco DRY: that requires two copies of the member list (and some order errors won't get caught!).  It also is reusable in `==` and `swap` and other methods this way.